# Insert new row containing a row id

Tags: oracle, rowid

I need to insert a new row with a new rowID. Does oracle do this automatically or is there something i need to use. I know with sequences you can do mysequence.nextVal or something similar. Is there anything like this for rowID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle handles rowid automatically. [RowId Info](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/rowid.html) and [more RowId Info](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c13datyp.htm#17757)